# How to run BacbPack for Laravel offline

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How can I run backpack styles offline (download css & js locally)?
I found a  PR in v4 but have not found how to apply this

Comment: What do you mean by "run" and "offline"? Are you facing any specific problem?

Answer (score 2):

negm

You would require the internet once to copy assets from CDNs to your local server.
The command `php artisan basset:cache` will go through all your blade files and internalize everything possible.

Notes:

- Ensure that `APP_URL` in your `.env` matches your server configuration, including the hostname, protocol, and port number. Incorrect settings can lead to asset-loading issues.
- Basset is disabled by default on the local environment. If you want to change it, please set `BASSET_DEV_MODE=false`
- Don't forget to do the storage link in case you haven't done it already; it's in [basset](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/basset) docs.

Find more info [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/basset?tab=readme-ov-file#the-basset-commands)